# How to find which clients are using a sendmail SMTP relay?

Tags: rhel, logs, sendmail

We have `sendmail` set up as a SMTP relay on a RHEL 6 machine.

How can we find the hostname or IP address of remote clients using this relay to send mail? Is this information logged somewhere?

The `relay=` field in `/var/log/maillog` specifies the hostname who accepted or rejected the mail recipient, which is not what we need.

Comment: how have you configured sendmail's logging?

Comment: AFAIK it's the default logging configuration: `mail.*   -/var/log/maillog` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be at least two lines logged in `/var/log/maillog` for each relayed message, identifiable by the matching Message-ID. The first one should record where the message was received **from**; the second documents where it was relayed **to**.

If your `sendmail` is configured with anti-malware and/or anti-spam checkers, there might be more lines for each processed message.